# WinAPI EM_STREAMOUT crash

Tags: c++, c, winapi, sendmessage, richedit

I'm trying to get the text of a Richedit Control from another program.

So I found EM_STREAMOUT for SendMessage.

This is my code so far (also from another Stackoverflow topic):

```
    DWORD CALLBACK EditStreamOutCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    std::stringstream *rtf = (std::stringstream*) dwCookie;
    rtf->write((char*)pbBuff, cb);
    *pcb = cb;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::stringstream rtf;

    EDITSTREAM es = {0};
    es.dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR) &rtf;
    es.pfnCallback = &EditStreamOutCallback;
    SendMessage((HWND) 0x00000000000A06E8, EM_STREAMOUT, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es);

}
```

The only thing that happens is that SendMessage returns 0 - so obviously no bytes were read - and the program of which I'm trying to get the information out of goes up to 100% CPU usage.

Comment: EM_STREAMOUT won't work across a process boundary. You would need to inject your code into the other process for this to work.

Comment: But reading text from normal edit controls with WM_GETTEXT works fine and I don't find anything in the MSDN which says that it doesn't work across process boundaries.

Comment: You found it in an SO comment.  It is correct.

Comment: Assuming that it is correct - how do i get the text out of a Richedit from another program? It must be possible because I'm able to do it in AutoIt which wraps around the WinAPI.

Comment: WM_GETTEXT will work, but if you want formatted text you'll have to inject your code.

Comment: got it...somehow I tested WM_GETTEXT but after many many hours of programming I kinda did it wrong the first time...thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

Some messages, like `WM_GETTEXT`, are marshaled by Windows for you. That is why you can retrieve a window's text across process boundaries.  `EM_STREAMIN/OUT` are not auto-marshaled.  That is why your code is crashing.  The `EDITSTREAM` struct and the callback code must exist in the address space of the same process that owns the RichEdit.

For many non-marshaled messages that need to cross process boundaries, you can allocate input/output buffers using `VirtualAllocEx()`, fill them using `WriteProcessMemory()`, and read from them using `ReadProcessMemory()`.  But because the `EDITSTREAM` callback code needs to be in the same process as well, you are best off moving your entire `EM_STREAMOUT` logic into a DLL and then inject it into the target process using `CreateRemoteThread()` or other injection technique.  You can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the process/thread IDs that own the RichEdit.  Your DLL can then retrieve the RichEdit data and send it back to your main app using any IPC (Inter-Process Communication) mechanism of your choosing, such as a named pipe, a mailslot, the  `WM_COPYDATA` message, etc.

Comment: Or simply take advantage of the [UI Automation Support for Standard Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671196.aspx).

Comment: Does UIA support retrieving a RichEdit's RTF instead of its plain text?

Comment: The question asks for *"the text of a RichEdit Control"*. While UI Automation does not directly allow access to the RTF, it offers interfaces to query text properties such as font face or color.

Comment: The *question* may say text, but the *code* says RTF. And having to scan the text querying for properties and ranges to gather formatting information is very inefficient.